# Is there a branch of CiviBooking compatible for 5.2x and PHP 7.3?

Tags: php7, civibooking, compatiblity

I am looking for a version of civibooking that works for 5.x since I was unable to get current version from official repo to work on civi 5.28 and Php 7.3. Please comment if you have one. Thanks

Comment: See this question and my comment https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37793/civicrm-5-29-0-installation-with-civibooking-1-5-3-causes-fatal-wordpress-error

Comment: @Tapash Did you ever come right with this? I see Andy's link is to a question that has since been removed.